# unmarshal generic json in Go

Tags: json, go

I'm a new Go programmer (From Java) and I would like to reproduce a generic way which is esay to use in Java.

I want to create some function which allow me to do an Unmarshal on a JSON string in order to avoid code duplicity.

This is my current code which is not working :

```
type myStruct1 struct {
    id string
    name string
}

func (obj myStruct1) toString() string {
    var result bytes.Buffer
    result.WriteString("id : ")
    result.WriteString(obj.id)
    result.WriteString("\n")
    result.WriteString("name : ")
    result.WriteString(obj.name)

    return result.String()
}

func main() {

    content := `{id:"id1",name="myName"}`
    object := myStruct1{}
    parseJSON(content, object)

    fmt.Println(object.toString()) 
}

func parseJSON(content string, object interface{}) {
    var parsed interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(content), &parsed)
}
```

This code, on run, returns me this :

```
id : 
name :
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: adding an abstraction to one line of code isn't solving duplicity, it's creating obfuscation.   Don't underestimate the power of simple readability of code.   `json.Unmarshal` is something everyone who reads your code will understand.  If I see `parseJSON` in a codebase, I'll have to go look at what that does because I'd never guess that a function was made to wrap an already simple construct.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advices. It's a Java dev behaviour to try to all factorize.
I guess it's a Go's thing I must adopt :)

Comment: I cant see it as a duplicate. But some people has marked it as duplicate. Here is a programmatic way to tackle the semi-structured objects in golang.

https://goplay.tools/snippet/fC7bI-Z6kK3

Idea is to create a recursive struct to represent semi-structured data.


type basic struct {
 AsNumber float64
 AsBool   bool
 AsStr    string
}

type Semi struct {
 AsArray []Semi
 AsObj   map[string]Semi
 AsPlain *basic
}

Comment: Your JSON string representation is wrong.

content := `{id:"id1",name="myName"}`

Should actually be
  
content := `{id:"id1",name:"myName"}`

If you had error handling you would see the json.Unmarshall was failing because of a bad string.

Answer (score 20):

The issue is you want to write to a generic type? You probably want a string map. This works with BSON anyways:

```
var anyJson map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(bytes, &anyJson)
```

You'll be able to access the fields like so:

```
anyJson["id"].(string)
```

Don't forget to type assert your values, and they **must** be the correct type or they'll panic. (You can read more about type assertions on the golang site)

Answer (score 5):

To parse "generic JSON" when you have no idea what schema it has:

```golang
    var parsed any
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonText, &parsed)
```

The returned `any` in `parsed` will be a `map[string]any` or `[]any` or `nil` or single values `float64`, `bool`, `string`.

You can test the type and react accordingly.

```golang
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func test(jsonText []byte) {
    // parsing
    var parsed any
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonText, &parsed)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // malformed input
    }

    // type-specific logic
    switch val := parsed.(type) {
    case nil:
        fmt.Println("json specifies null")
    case map[string]any:
        fmt.Printf("id:%s name:%s\n", val["id"], val["name"])
    case []any:
        fmt.Printf("list of %d items\n", len(val))
    case float64:
        fmt.Printf("single number %f\n", val)
    case bool:
        fmt.Printf("single bool %v\n", val)
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("single string %s\n", val)
    default:
        panic(fmt.Errorf("type %T unexpected", parsed))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unmarshal will only set exported fields of the struct.

Which means you need to modify the json struct to use capital case letters:

```
type myStruct1 struct {
    Id string
    Name string
}
```

The reason behind this is that the json library does not have the ability to view fields using reflect unless they are exported.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few changes you need to make in your code to make it work:

1. The function `json.Unmarshal` can only set variables inside your struct which are exported, that is, which start with capital letters. Use something like `ID` and `Name` for your variable names inside `myStruct1`.
2. Your content is invalid JSON. What you actually want is `{"ID":"id1","Name":"myName"}`.
3. You're passing `object` to `parseJSON` but you're using `parsed` instead, not `object`. Make `parseJSON` receive a `*myStruct` (instead of an `interface{}`), and use that variable instead of `parsed` when unmarshalling the string. Also, *always* handle the error returns, like `err := json.Unmarshal(content, object)`, and check `err`.

I'd suggest you to do the [Golang Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) ;)

Comment: Thanks for your tips, i'm afraid i didn't have corrected my code before sent it, i'm sorry.
The problem about your 3rd tip is that I want to be able to use as well myStruct1 and myStruct2 as parameter of parseJSON. Have you any idea ?

Comment: well, you can use `interface{}` then, but you still don't need to declare `parsed`. And there won't be a lot of advantage in having the function `parseJSON` if all it does is to call another function, `json.Unmarshal` :-) But yes, you can leave it as `interface{}` as well, I just like to make things more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export your fields:

```
type myStruct1 struct {
        Id string
        Name string
}
```

See [Exported Identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) from documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You can also set the file as an Object with dynamic properties inside another struct. This will let you add metadata and you read it the same way.

```
type MyFile struct {
    Version string
    Data  map[string]interface{}
}
```